# Редактирование содержания сообщения в telegram боте из документа в текст и обратно (python, aiogram3)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

У меня есть сервис в боте, который позволяет по нажатию Inline кнопки формировать документ и отправлять его пользователю.
Вопрос такой: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы содержание сообщения менялось из текста на документ и обратно (как метод edit_text)?
python, aiogram3

```
async def get_history(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
await state.update_data(assistant_key=call.data)
context_data = await state.get_data()
if call.data == 'back':
    await call.message.edit_text(main_menu_text, reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard)
    # содержание сообщения должно меняться с документа на текст (сейчас выдает ошибку)
    await state.set_state(UserMenu.MAIN_MENU)
elif call.data:
    if db.check_user_in_subscriptions(call.data, call.from_user.id) is True:
        name = db.subscription_info(context_data.get("assistant_key"))[0]
        path = create_file(call.from_user.id, call.from_user.username, name, context_data.get("assistant_key"))
        file = FSInputFile(path)
        await call.message.answer_document(file, reply_markup=back_keyboard) 
        # сообщение содержит документ (сообщение ответное, хотелось бы чтобы оно именно менялось)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            os.remove(path)
        else:
            print(f"Error: {path} file not found")
    else:
        await call.answer(f"Вы не подписаны на этот чат", show_alert=True)
else:
    await call.answer(f"Не найдена команда {call.data}", show_alert=True)
```